# How to add a project to build path in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've recently converted over to IntelliJ Idea 13, previously in eclipse I was able to add a project to another project's build path. I'm not able to accomplish this in IntelliJ.

How can I add project1 to project2's build path so that I can use it as a dependency. I don't want to make that project a JAR because I'm still developing it.

Following this similar previous question:
[Intellij - Add project dependency like in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865313/intellij-add-project-dependency-like-in-eclipse)

I was not able to successfully achieve my goal.

In File > Project Structure > Modules

I see the project I'd like to add to my build path (DataProvider) but it's highlighted red, and the bottom warning text states "Invalid item 'DataProvider' in dependencies list'

[image]

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

**Solution** (Thanks @leeor)

Import project as a module

File > Import Module > (Select Project to be imported)

This will add that project to the project view pane on the left side of the screen.

Then go to your current project

File > Project Structure > Module > (Select your current project)

Under Dependencies

Check mark your project (now a module) you want to import and then click apply and then OK.

Done!

Using IntelliJ Idea 13.1.6 on Mac

Comment: I tried these steps but couldn't get it working. I'm migrating from Eclipse and am not sure what may be going wrong. Both the projects which I want to import from Eclipse are maven based. I did exactly same steps as you mentioned. But IDEA still complains and doesn't recognize the dependancy added

Comment: can you please add the screen shot of the current working dependent module on project ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to depend on another module without it being jar, you need to import that as a module into the same project. It doesn't look like `DataProvider` is imported since it doesn't appear in the module list.

Comment: @leeor does this work for you with current version of IDEA ? I'm struggling to get it working from last 1 day but no success yet.