# File Not found, is my package setup correctly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, filenotfoundexception

I should first mention that I'm still an undergraduate, so excuse "beginner" mistakes, I'm also using the intellij IDE.

It's entirely possible that I'm missing something rather obvious but why is this .txt file not found when it's in a source root. My package hierarchy looks to be fine.

Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

[As you can see fileNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ea5r.png)

Comment: where is the code ? no clue what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry about that, added a screenshot.

Comment: If your file is on the classpath, you can get an `InputStream` using `PathFinding.class.getResourceAsStream("com/.../.../.../the_file.txt")`, try replacing the `new File(...)` bit with something like that

Comment: Check what is actual running directory of your progam, because you use relative path to your file. Simple add a line System.out.println(new File("./").getAbsolutePath()).That relative path you provided must not be in that directory. BTW it is better to start relative path from current directory with "./". I.e. >/com/jenkyn.... etc.

Comment: Appreciate the comments, helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your project is not on build path . On Intellij you can configure it as mentioned in this post:

[How to add a project to build path in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832059/how-to-add-a-project-to-build-path-in-intellij-idea)

And then you can access it using absolute path :

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/path/to/file.txt");
```

Or relative CLASSPATH path (when the class you are writing is in the same Java package as the resource file itself):

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

I would also suggest you to read here: 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was in the buildpath however I was referencing the absolute path slightly incorrectly. The link was also useful.