# Undefined steps after running test from TestRunner class

Tags: cucumber-java, test-runner

I have a very strange situation, I have created `Features` and `Scenarios` in the feature file and corresponding step definitions and methods in the separate class.

I have run tests by running a feature file, and everything was fine, all tests were green.

But, when I run tests from `TestRunner` class, I got the following message:

> Undefined step: Given I am on the Facebook Login page and suggested code.

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^I am on the Facebook Login page$")
public void i_am_on_the_Facebook_Login_page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

I have noticed that the suggested method have underscore:

```
(i_am_on_the_Facebook_Login_page())
```

but my methods do not have underscore

```
(iAmOnTheFacebookLoginPage())
```

Does anybody have an idea why this happens? I can't run tests now even from the feature file.

Recently, I have started using **Mac** and **IntelliJ** instead of **Windows** and **Eclipse**.

Is it possible that **IntelliJ** causes the problem?
P.S. I have used the option "Create step definition" from **IntelliJ**

Answer (score 0):

ah...I figured out what the problem was...I forgot to put this piece of code 
`snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE` 
in CucumberOptions.

So, when I put this line of code here

`@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"}, glue = {"/java/stepDefinitions"}, snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE)`

everything works just fine.

Comment: ...but now I have a problem to run tests from feature file, now I got an Undefined step message... when running tests from the feature file. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your project structure? More specifically, I'm interested in where the features and step definition folder are located.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your features folder is not in the build path (being a test folder) so Cucumber is unable to find it. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832059/how-to-add-a-project-to-build-path-in-intellij-idea).